# SVN privilege for newly created user

Tags: php, sudo

I am required to create a new user and then `svn co` into the newly created user's home directory by calling a bash script from a php page.

The below example is a line from the sudoers file which I saw at some other forum.

```
http ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/useradd,/bin/mkdir,/bin/ln,/bin/chown,/bin/cp,/bin/sed
```

This line obviously sets a passwordless sudo for the user `http` and adds privileges to the user `http` to use `useradd`, `mkdir`, `chown`, `cp` and `sed`commands. I would not like to disable the sudo prompt for all users but just for the newly created user (I had seen an answer regarding commenting a certain line in the sudoers file for preventing the sudo password prompt here at AU).

Similarly I would like to add svn privileges onto the `www-data` user.

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd,/bin/svn
```

Currently the `www-data` user is able to create a new user using the `useradd` command, but is unable to use the svn command. ( I may be doing it completely wrong so feel free to correct me)

This is the bash script that I am trying to run.

```
sudo useradd newuser -d /home/newuser -s /bin/bash -m -p password
echo yes | sudo svn --username [username] --password [password] co [SVN link] /home/newuser/public_html
```

When I try to call this script from the php page using the command

`$output = shell_exec("sh ./includes/setupsite.sh 2>&1");`

I get the error

`sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` for the second line (the `svn co` line)

But instead when I try to run without `sudo` I get

`----------------------------------------------------------------------- ATTENTION! Your password for authentication realm: Authentication Required can only be stored to disk unencrypted! You are advised to configure your system so that Subversion can store passwords encrypted, if possible. See the documentation for details. You can avoid future appearances of this warning by setting the value of the 'store-plaintext-passwords' option to either 'yes' or 'no' in '/var/www/.subversion/servers'. ----------------------------------------------------------------------- Store password unencrypted (yes/no)? svn: Can't make directory '/home/newuser/public_html': Permission denied`

So that made it obvious that sudo might be required. I saw a similar question here itself. But that was not answered and the answer provided didn't solve my issue.

Update: The file permissions/ownership are:

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  326 2012-08-08 17:56 setupsite.sh`

If you need any clarifications please leave a comment and I'll edit my question to add those details (provided that I have them) ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `which [command]` lets you know which terminal command is being called.

For example in my question I have entered a `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd`, notice the last part `/usr/bin/useradd` this is the actual location of the useradd command that is called by the terminal. This may be obtained by use of `which useradd`.

Similarly you can also add search for the `svn` command using `which svn` and this will give you the location of the `svn` command. In my case, it gave me `/usr/bin/svn` and so when I edited the line

`www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd,/bin/svn`

into

`www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd,/usr/bin/svn`

the www-data user got svn privileges and I was able to do password-less sudo for the www-data user.